# Protocol Composition can't be used in struct in swift

Tags: swift

protocol is a kind of type in swift and should be used in everywhere as a type, so *why Protocol Composition can't be used in struct in swift?*

```
protocol Named {
    var name: String { get }
}
protocol Aged {
    var age: Int { get }
}
struct Person: Named, Aged {
    var name: String
    var age: Int
}
func wishHappyBirthday(to celebrator: Named & Aged) {
    print("Happy birthday, \(celebrator.name), you're \(celebrator.age)!")
}
let birthdayPerson = Person(name: "Malcolm", age: 21)
wishHappyBirthday(to: birthdayPerson)
// Prints "Happy birthday, Malcolm, you're 21!"
```

In **struct Person**, if I change it into

```
struct Person: Named & Aged {
    var name: String
    var age: Int
}
```

the complier error appears： Protocol composition is neither allowed nor needed here

So why I can use Protocol composition in **function** rather than **struct**?

Comment: Too much abstraction is never good.

Comment: Whats wrong with the syntax `struct Person: Named, Aged {`?

Comment: The purpose is to be able to pass any struct that conforms to Named and Aged, not only Person. For instance you could create a struct called Pet that conforms to Named and Aged but it is not a Person and this way wishHappyBirthday would not be restricted to Persons only

Comment: For that particular example `struct Person: Named, Aged {}` and `struct Pet: Named {}` would satisfy all your requirements